# Simple database. Foreign keys insertion

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 categories A and B with the following columns:

**Category A**

```
_id | name
```

**Category B**

```
_id | tableA_id |name
```

**Item List**

```
_id | name | tableB_id
```

`tableA_id` and `tableB_id` are foreign keys and _id columns are primary keys.

Category B is a sub-category of A.

`name` columns are unique (there will be just 1 category in each table)

I want to insert 5 items each with their category A and B.

**Item 1:**

```
name: item1
category A: Movie
Category B: Action
```

**Item 2:**

```
name: item2
category A: Movie
Category B: Drama
```

**Item 3:**

```
name: item3
category A: Movie
Category B: Comedy
```

**Item 4:**

```
name: item4
category A: Music
Category B: Pop
```

**Item 5:**

```
name: item5
category A: Music
Category B: Rock
```

How can I populate the foreign keys without querying the ids of their correspondent primary?

Or am I missing an important part of DB design?

Answer (score 1):

If your database design is 'correct', to prevent corruption you will not be able to insert child records without their parent keys.

In order to get the parent key, without doing a re-query, read this excellent post:

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record

Answer (score 1):

> How can I populate the foreign keys without querying the ids of their correspondent primary?

If I understand your question correctly, you cannot populate the foreign keys when inserting new record into table `List` without querying the ids of Rock, that is without

```
select _id,  tableA_id
from Category_B
where name = 'Rock'
```

Answer (score 1):

First populate CATEGORY_A and CATEGORY_B.

Then insert into ITEM_LIST knowing CATEGORY_B.ID.

Comment: What you are saying is, to insert an item, I must: 1- insert Category A, 2 - query the _id of A and insert category B, and then query _id of Category B  and insert Item? I think its too much operations to insert a single item. Isn't there another way?

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing the IDs are sequences generated by the RDBMS, else you would already know the values.

Comment: I also sugest you add a unique index on the name of the category and a trigger to convert it to either all uppercase or all lowercase on insert. Else you will end up with a "MOVIE" category, a "movie" category,a "Movie" category, a "mOvie" category and so on.